I need help with translation Chinese address
I am returning an item to a Chinese seller on aliexpress, and this is the return address I was given:
Roland 18897729810
China Guangdong province Dongguan Fenggang Town 5th floor, Unit 3, Building 1, Ahne Innovation and Technology Park, No. 16, Bihu Road CN 523686 - Dongguan - Guangdong Province.
Can someone please give me Street name and Business name so I can fill paper for Post office, Thank you!

I recall writing a detailed answer to a similar question here.  In any case:

Roland 18897729810

This is the name and phone number.  The most important thing on the Chinese side is the phone number.

China Guangdong province Dongguan Fenggang Town 5th floor, Unit 3, Building 1, Ahne Innovation and Technology Park, No. 16, Bihu Road CN 523686

You could just write this, and it'll be fine, but let's break it into Chinese:

China = 中国
Guangdong Province = 广东省
Dongguan City = 东莞市 (the 市 means "city")
Fenggang Town = 凤岗镇 (the 镇 is like "town")
Bihu Road = 碧湖路 (the 路 is "road")
5th floor = 5层
Unit 3 = 3单元
Building 1 = 1栋
Ahne Innovation and Technology Park = 安和创新科技园 (note that Ahne seems to be a misspelling of Anhe)
No. 16 = 16号
Postcode = 523686

Thus in Chinese it's:

中国广东省东莞市凤岗镇碧湖路安和创新科技园1栋3单元5层16号523686

It's here on Baidu Maps, and here's one of its photos:




中国广东省东莞市丰港镇1栋3单元5层， Ahne(?)创新科技园，16号，bihu（？）路
there are some parts that I cannot translate because there is no ton of those chinese characters, but I've translated the most part of the address.
